# Same id's but only fetch 1 result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm about to make a message system. Instead of making 2 tables like `conversations` and `messages`, I would just like to have `messages`. There would then be a lot of rows with the same user id's like this:

```
id     to_id     from_id     message
1      1         2           text...
2      1         3           text...
3      2         1           text...
4      1         2           text...
5      1         2           text...
6      1         2           text...
```

The thing is, that I want to get one of each conversation. If id 1 writes to id 2, then thats 1 conversation, but if id 2 writes a reply to id 1, then it would STILL be only 1 conversation.

In the above example, there is only 2 conversations (id 1 to id 3) and (id 1 to id 2 and reverse).

How can i Achieve this. My idea is that there must be something simpler than DISTINCT.

Comment: Why not generate a new or use an existing `conv_id` when creating the record?

Comment: @AbraCadaver See.... that's why I hate myself sometimes. Post an answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might go for a related table but to keep it simple, just add the column `conv_id`.

When a message is created, create a new `conv_id` and add it to the table row with the other data.  When a message is replied to just use that `conv_id` for the new row.

When you want to retrieve conversation(s) either select `WHERE conv_id=x` and/or use a `GROUP BY conv_id`.

Comment: I could easily make another table, but why would it be good to have 2 tables instead of one? Is the performance worse?

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you use group by to join conversations :

```
select * from table where to_id = 1 group by from_id
```

Comment: What if from_id=2 and to_id=3?  Then that would be included in the 2 to 1 conversation and the 1 to 2 would be a separate conversation.